# Check if picture is selected from photo library

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

The user can select a picture as a profile picture in my app.
After that he can click on done and the picture gets uploaded.
If the user does not select a picture my code still upload a blank picture by clicking on done.

How can I check if the user selected a picture and then trigger the function?
I need an if else statement but don't know how to get the status "is a picture selected?"

I could maybe also use a default value. But that would mean to download the actual picture and reupload it again as default. That does not sound good.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tapToChangeProfileButton: UIButton!
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    
    @IBAction func updateProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {
               
        uploadPic(arg: true, completion: { (success) -> Void in
               if success {
                   addUrlToFirebaseProfile()
               } else {
               }
           })
        
        
        func uploadPic(arg: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
            
            guard let imageSelected = self.image else {
                completion(false);
                return
                
            }
            guard let imageData = imageSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) else {
                completion(false);
                return
                
            }
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://....e.appspot.com")
            let storageProfileRef = storageRef.child("profilePictures").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
            storageProfileRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: {
                (storageMetadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    //print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    completion(false);
                    return
                }
                storageProfileRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if let metaImageURL = url?.absoluteString {
                        print(metaImageURL)
                        self.urltoPicture = metaImageURL
                        completion(true)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completion(false); return
                    }
                })
            })
            
        }
        
        func addUrlToFirebaseProfile(){
            ref = Database.database().reference()
            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
            ref.child("user/\(userID)").updateChildValues(["profileText": profileText.text!])
            print(urltoPicture)
            ref.child("user/\(userID)").updateChildValues(["picture": urltoPicture])
        }
                                                       
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openImagePicker))
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
        tapToChangeProfileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
}

 @objc func openImagePicker(_ sender:Any){
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

extension ImagePickerViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any])
    {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.profileImageView.image = pickedImage
            
            image = pickedImage
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your code, whenever you get an image from `imagePickerController` you store it into variable `self.image`. Then whenever you click Done you just upload this `self.image`

Make variable `self.image` can be nil then remember to unset it after uploading successfully

Code will be like this

```swift
var image : UIImage? = nil

@IBAction func updateProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {
    uploadPic(arg: true, completion: { (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            addUrlToFirebaseProfile()
            self.image = nil // reset image to nil if success
        } else {
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After looking through your code I understood it.

Comment: That's insufficient. `self.image` needs to be `nil` at _all_ times when there is not a currently selected image in play.

Comment: Dear @matt, because I don't see where the author set his ``self.image`` so I just only notice him about the ``self.image`` should be nil after upload success. I think he can realize the rest.

Comment: I completely agree! That's why I told the OP the code provided in the question was insufficient. I just wanted to bring out this point.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `self.image` if the user selects a photo.

But you are not *unsetting* `self.image` if the user *doesn't* select a photo. It needs to be set to `nil` (not to an empty `UIImage()`).

Comment: ok and how can I unset if the user does not select a photo?

Comment: I've told you everything I can based on the insufficient code you've shown. You will be fine if you think about the logic and apply it.

Comment: At SO we don't write your code for you. I think what I've said is both correct and useful. Observe that the other answer says just the same thing, independently.